# Code Behind the "Add to My Drive" Button

Tags: c#, file-io, google-drive-api

I was wondering if anybody has had to write a program which moves a folder from "shared with me" to "My Drive". I am trying to do this, but cannot find any Google source code anywhere for moving files. There is code to cop the file, but I do not want to create a copy, I want to move the location of the file from the "Shared with me" folder to the "My Drive" folder. I do not have any ideas as I have looked and looked and looked without finding anything related to moving a file, and I also cannot post any code snippets as I have none. :(

**EDIT:** This is being done on a service account and being shared with thousands of users, so currently they would all need to authorize the app. We want to be able to share it with them and put it into their drive too. We tried briefly by giving them ownership, which worked, but giving them ownership is **not** an option.

So, the user will have the file shared with them, and then we want to put it directly into their drive for their convenience.

Answer (score 0):

`Shared with me`, or in the new UI, 'Incoming' isn't really a folder - it is more a view of information shared with you. As such, you cannot 'Move' in the traditional sense, but you can definitely add it to my Drive.

It is really simply to do programmatically if you have the file ID you wish to add. Have a read of [parents.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/insert) for code. All you need to do is add 'root' as a parent of the folder you wish to add. root=My Drive.

[.NET example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/insert#examples). Note, just set folderId to "root".

Hope that helps!

Comment: This works if it is in my drive, but we are doing this in a whole network, and we don't have the user's passwords so we can't do it as of yet. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

"Add to My Drive" work by adding parent to the file. use `drive.files.update`, example request

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID?addParents=PARENT_ID&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```